# Can use environment variables with the sub intrinsic function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am using the sub function to define a resource within an aws IAM service.

```
Resource:
  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::example-${TEST1}-${AWS::REGION}-test'
```

${TEST1}: it is an environment variable that I have in my java project.

${AWS::REGION}: pseudo parameter

I want to know if !sub is able to read the environment variable and if it can't, is there any way I can do it even if it's not with this function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you cannot reference environment variables within cloudformation.

You'll have to wrap the cloudformation deployment with a script that parses the environment variables and feeds them in as parameters, which can then be referenced in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Make the environment variable a CloudFormation Parameter and set the value. Then !Sub will work as expected. You can create a parameter file if you need to massage the values with sed or jq.

Comment: How's this different compared to my answer?

Comment: It's not your answer was more than likely not seen while I had this question open. As it's a duplicate I can remove it. Thanks!